# Did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, ansible

Am running ansible play-book but getting below error, -using ansible 2.7.6, ubuntu 16.04.
in playbook am mentioned

```
(<unknown>): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 6 column 3
```

I tried without become-yes,ubuntu,sudo that also getting the same issue and ansible saying:

```
The offending line appears to be:


   - name: build npm
   ^ here
```

```
 - hosts: all
   vars:
       app_dir: /home/ubuntu/app/backend-app-name
   tasks:
 - name: build npm
   command: "chdir={{ app_dir }} {{ item }}"
     with_items:
     - /usr/bin/npm run build
      become: yes
      become_user: ubuntu
      become_method: sudo
```

Answer (score 21):

Indentation is wrong. Correct syntax is

```
   tasks:
     - name: build npm
       command: ...
       with_items:
         - /usr/bin/npm run build
       become: yes
       become_user: ubuntu
       become_method: sudo
```

Comment: if I need to run npm buil first I need to go that directory then  run npm buil, both commands need to run together, I tried the same what you seggested but getting the same error
`- name: build npm
       command: chdir=/home/ubuntu/app/backend-app-name {{ item }}
       with_items:
         - /usr/bin/npm run build
       become: yes
       become_user: ubuntu
       become_method: sudo
`

Comment: Any alternative solution for run npm build using ansible, anyway below yml file not getting any error, but build not happening.
`- name: npm build
      command: chdir=/home/ubuntu/node-path/app-name/ npm run build
      become: yes
      become_user: root`

Comment: The indentation was the problem. With my VS Code configuration, saving also auto-formats my code and in this case it shifted a lot of code by one tab to the right. I had to change this to shift the code back to the start (one tab to the left), for it to work.

Answer (score 7):

I received this same error when there was an extra single-quote in the YAML task.

> While parsing a block mapping, did not find expected key.

```
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      inputs:
        command: 'pack'
        packagesToPack: '**/DoesNotMatter/OL.csproj'
        #...
        versionEnvVar: 'PACKAGEVERSION''
```

See last (extra `'`) character of code sample.

Answer (score -4):

#### Removed Trailing Whitespace

I had a similar issue when rubocop parsed the yaml file.

```
› ruby_koans (mark) rubocop --auto-gen-config
(.rubocop.yml): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 1 column 1
```

Removed trailing white space.  (in VSCode using "Trim Trailing Whitespace" setting.

```
› ruby_koans (mark) rubocop --auto-gen-config
Added inheritance from `.rubocop_todo.yml` in `.rubocop.yml`.
Phase 1 of 2: run Layout/LineLength cop
Inspecting 42 files
```